# Column value for min and max date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following data (SQL server 2014):

```
          Event        Start             End    Pres_Avg    Pres_Min    Pres_Max    Pres_Start  Pres_End 
 11-PSV-401002A 4-4-16 12:51    4-4-16 13:58    6.07990537  6.05642176  6.10893869  6.07731962  6.05642176
 11-PSV-401002A 4-4-16 14:04    4-4-16 14:29    6.09301376  6.0584569   6.13351011  6.06586695  6.0584569
 11-PSV-401002A 4-4-16 14:38    4-4-16 15:09    6.10506467  6.05952168  6.12660933  6.06916332  6.05952168
```

And I use following query to get average for Pres_Avg and min and max for Pres_Min and Pres_Max:

```
select [Event], 
   min([Start ]) [Start ], 
   max([End ]) [End ], 
   avg([Pres_Avg]) [Pres_Avg],
   Min([Pres_Min]) [Pres_Min],
   Max([Pres_Max]) [Pres_Max]
from y
group by [Event], g
```

I'd like to get Pres_Start for where Pres_Start is for min([Start ]) = 6.07731962  and Pres_End where Pres_End is for max([End ]) = 6.05952168.
How can I make it in the same query?

```
          Event        Start             End    Pres_Avg    Pres_Min    Pres_Max    Pres_Start  Pres_End 
 11-PSV-401002A 4-4-16 12:51    4-4-16 15:09    6.092661    6.05642176  6.13351011  6.07731962  6.05952168
```

I'd like Something like code below in one query since I already getting min and start dates:

```
select [Event], 
   min([Start ]) [Start ], 
   max([End ]) [End ], 
   avg([Pres_Avg]) [Pres_Avg],
   Min([Pres_Min]) [Pres_Min],
   Max([Pres_Max]) [Pres_Max],
   min([Start ]) and Pres_Start value, 
   max([End ]) and Pres_End value
from y
group by [Event], g
```

thanks

Comment: Provide  your expected result in table format

Comment: @Clar Cleetus: see update

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join back again with your table y twice, to retrieve the rows with the start and end values you need. You can do this by putting your query into a sub query, and then joining with y twice:

```
select y_grouped.*
    , y_start.Pres_Start 
    , y_end.Pre_End
from ( select [Event], 
           min([Start ]) [Start ], 
           max([End ]) [End ], 
           avg([Pres_Avg]) [Pres_Avg],
           Min([Pres_Min]) [Pres_Min],
           Max([Pres_Max]) [Pres_Max]
       from y
       group by [Event], g ) y_grouped
inner join y y_start on y_grouped.[Start ] = y_start.[Start ]
inner join y y_end on y_grouped.[End ] = y_end.[End ]
```

It's hard to be totally sure this will work without having sample data to run it on, but give it a go, and let us know how it turns out!

Also be aware, that if you have multiple rows with either the same start date, or the same end date, you could get multiple rows in this query. If this is the case, then specify how you would choose between those 2 rows to get your Pres_Start and Pres_End values.

For a one line method, you can do the following:

```
select [Event], 
   min([Start ]) [Start ], 
   max([End ]) [End ], 
   avg([Pres_Avg]) [Pres_Avg],
   Min([Pres_Min]) [Pres_Min],
   Max([Pres_Max]) [Pres_Max],
   (select top 1 Pres_Start from @y y2 where y1.[Event] = y2.event and y1.g = y2.g order by [Start ] asc) Pres_Start,
   (select top 1 Pres_End from @y y2 where y1.[Event] = y2.event and y1.g = y2.g order by [End ] desc) Pres_End
from @y as y1
group by [Event], g
```

Comment: thanks for code. I just thought there is some eficient way to get in one code row, since I already getting min and max dates so just take values comes with these min and max dates. Something like update from main code (will put in minue).

Comment: I had another thought, and edited my answer with a method that may work for you - it is indeed in one line! Sorry - should have realised there would be a way somehow!